# How to format data to send vanilla XHR formated like jQuery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a POST XHRequest that works as intended with jQuery, but not in vanilla JS.

Because I'm trying to learn all the inner workings of JS, I would like to use as much vanilla code as possible. I know about Fetch API, but I'm really new to all this, and really want to understand better.
So, here is the issue I'm currently facing (for over a week now):

I have this code, that works:

```js
    let packg = {
        schema: 'string',
        table: 'anotherString'
    };
    
    const packgJSON = JSON.stringify(packg);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/get_data.php',
        data: {'content': packgJSON}
    });
```

This is the result in Firefox Developer Tools, that works perfectly with my PHP file:

[image: Printscreen of Firefox Developer Tools]

When I try to write vanilla JS, like this:

```js
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', 'php/get_data.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    let packg = {
        schema: 'string',
        table: 'anotherString'
    };

    const packgJSON = JSON.stringify(packg);

    xhr.send({'content': packgJSON});
```

This is the results I get:

[image: Printscreen of Firefox Developer Tools]

I can't understand how I should format the `.send()` content in order to go formatted like the jQuery request. I have tried other options I found in MDN, W3Schools, You Might Not Need jQuery, etc, but the request is never like the jQuery one. I am clearly failing to understand basic concepts of JS objects and strings, but I do not understand at all what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XMLHttpRequest.send`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) does not take a plain object as a parameter like jQuery ajax does.
You can however use that object to create a `URLSearchParams` object and pass that to send

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'php/get_data.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

let packg = {
    schema: 'string',
    table: 'anotherString'
};

const packgJSON = JSON.stringify(packg);
var data = new URLSearchParams({'content': packgJSON})
xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla js your request would look something like this

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = '/api/endpoint';
var params = 'orem=ipsum&name=binny' // Or your json;
http.open('POST', url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

first you make a new XMLHTTPREQUEST and you open the request and provide method and url

```
http.open('POST', url, true);
```

the third parameter is to make the request async as mdn documentation mentions

> An optional Boolean parameter, defaulting to true, indicating whether
> or not to perform the operation asynchronously. If this value is
> false, the send() method does not return until the response is
> received. If true, notification of a completed transaction is provided
> using event listeners. This must be true if the multipart attribute is
> true, or an exception will be thrown.

then you will send the request with the body as an argument

> http.send(params);

and you listen for changes and responses in the request using these event listener

```
http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
```